Can the water in a vegetable get replaced with another liquid without damaging the structure of the vegetable?
I was watching this year's episode of preserving pumpkins in resin by Evan and Katelyn when I had an idea that I am trying to look deeper into. As the title suggests, I am looking for a fluid that by some method can be used to displace the water in a pumpkin (or other fruit/veg) so it can be preserved with a resin process.
In every iteration of these episodes the pumpkins end up cracking, deforming, etc. in a way that makes them strikingly different from a fresh pumpkin. This year they tried freeze drying and had some fairly decent results, but while watching the pumpkins cracking once again I wondered if there is a way to keep them moist, while removing the water. If I can find a fluid that has the ability to displace the water and is also non conducive to the processes that decompose fruits and veg, it might be possible to perfectly preserve a carved pumpkin.
Bonus points if this fluid won't interfere with resin.

Just an idea: polyethylene glycol was used to preserve the wood in the Vasa presumably by slowly replacing the water, so might be worth a try.

Didn't they use formalin like that? Though, I guess, it wasn't terribly safe.

Solvent exchange could be done in multiple steps. It takes very long time. Starting with more polar solvent, then less polar at each step. Something like: Aqueous... methanol... ethanol... propanol... alkanes.

I haven't tried myself, so this is not an official answer.

Removing water and replacing with other material is commonly done when making permanent slides for microscopy. It  was performed a century and a half ago for optical microscopy and is still performed for electron microscopy.
The general procedure is to immerse the specimen is a series of water/alcohol (ethanol is most often used) mixtures, starting with perhaps 80% water/ 20% alcohol, then 60:40, then 40:60, then 20:80, and finally absolute alcohol.
Why all that bother? Couldn't one just go to 100% alcohol directly? The answer is that the strong osmotic difference between cell contents and surrounding fluid would cause cells to be badly distorted.
Ah... but one is not done yet. The alcohol must be replaced by a nonpolar solvent that is compatible with the embedding material (e.g., wax or epoxy resin). This calls for more steps through alcohol/acetone, alcohol/xylene, or other baths. Been there, done that... it's slow.
Ah! But you want to embed a larger specimen, such as a pumpkin. there are two issues:

Sufficient time must be given in each bath for the solvent to fully penetrate the specimen, reaching equilibrium. For a piece of onion skin or slice of plant stem 100 µm thick, this might take 5 minutes in each bath.
For a single blueberry, each step might take an hour. For a green pea, with thicker skin , or a whole insect, a day might be needed in each. Will any of these penetrate the pumpkin rind in a reasonable length of time?

Also, calculate the quantity of solvents needed for your hypothetical preserved pumpkin, and then the cost of a pumpkin's-worth bath series.


